# Google Charts Annotated Time Line - adjust y-axis on zoom

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, annotatedtimeline

I am using the [annotated time line chart](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line) in google charts API.  I have a long time line of data (20 years) and range of the data goes from about 0 to 900,000 (see picture)  If you zoom on the most recent year, the max from this set is only about 400,000.  So when we zoom in, I don't need the y-axis to go all the way to 900,000, but only to 400,000.  This way the chart would be easier to read.

What I would like to achieve is the chart to re-adjust the maximum vertical axis value every time I adjust the zoom.

[image]

Zoom in on most recent year:

[image]

Before I start hacking my way through this, does anyone know a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *scaleType* [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline#Configuration_Options).  Specify value of *maximized* if you have one series.  Specify *allmaximized* if you have more than one series.  This snippet works on the [code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line):

```
  var annotatedtimeline = new google.visualization.AnnotatedTimeLine(
      document.getElementById('visualization'));
  annotatedtimeline.draw(data, {'scaleType':'allmaximized'});
```